# Chained methods

Tags: c#, .net

A long time ago, I saw something that allowed you to chain a series of methods together dynamically. Can't remember if it was in C#, or C++.

It goes something like this:

Methods:

```
Foo();
Bar();
Moar();
```

An object is then created that subscribes (for lack of a better word) to any or all of the methods above (depending on the programmer's specification), and whatever is passed into this object will run through all the subscribed methods.

I ask, because I am working on a kernel for a program, which depending on a variety of choices, may or may not need certain methods. Since this program needs to be very tightly coded (I prefer not to waste a processor cycle on an if / else statement...it will add up), I was wondering if anyone recalls what I am attempting to convey, and what the C# equivalent would be.

Thanks,
-R

Comment: You know there are billions of processor cycles every second?  You won't be wasting them unless you're doing very intensive data processing..  out of interest what is the app doing?

Comment: Genetic algorithms, fitness functions, perceptron backpropagation etc?  There are some decent libraries that handle that stuff in .NET I imagine, but it's fun to implement stuff from scratch I guess :)  I guess it's not for use in a game or live setting per se (wouldn't be that intensive), but training some neural net or parameters for later use..

Comment: If you're so concerned about 'wasting a cycle' on if statements, are you sure C# is the right language to do this in to begin with?

Comment: Yes. Actually closer to genetic programming than genetic algorithms, with all the usual applications that stem from a decent design. When I've finished with the C# kernel, I'll be working on the OpenCl kernel. However, harmonizing C# and C is proving to be interesting. C# calculates one value from an equation, while C calculates something else.

Comment: Yes. I've weighed C#'s capabilities, strengths and weaknesses against a pure C / C++ design, and while I may be sacrificing some speed up front, the stuff I want to do later on will benefit from this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *sounds* like an event:

declared:

```
public event Action Something;
```

subscribed:

```
obj.Something += x.Foo;
...
obj.Something += y.Bar;
...
obj.Something += z.Moar;
```

then invoked:

```
protected virtual void OnSomething() {
    var handler = Something;
    if(handler != null) handler();
}
...
OnSomething(); // call ^^^^^^
```

which would invoke all the 3 methods, but with loose coupling.

Note you can do exactly the same just with a *delagate* rather than an event. Note also that events *generally* have a more specific `void (object sender, SomeEventArgs args)` signature (but this is convention, not a requirement).

Comment: Should that be `if (handler != null)`?

Comment: Agreed, it does sound like an event, but if I remember correctly, it is not. It's one of those things I read about in a book from several years ago, kind of laughed at the idea of using (when am I ever going to use that), and am now kicking myself for not remembering.

Comment: @Kirk indeed; I guess I must have been javascript lately!

Comment: @user978122 can you be more specific about the differences, so we can help?

Comment: Unfortunately, none come to mind. I'll be tearing through my library tonight to find out if any of my books contain the reference. Just can't remember if it is a C++ or a C# thing.

Answer (score 2):

Marc's answer is the closest in C#, but it's worth pointing out - this would not be faster than a series of `if`s, it would be slower.

Perhaps you are referring to the way you can `JMP` to another address in assembler at the end of a method to avoid a `CALL` and two subsequent `RET`s - that's X86 assembler, but modern optimising compilers will make the optimisation for you.

I.e., you call a method with `CALL`, that pushes the return address to the stack, then at the end of the other method, you might `CALL` another, but then it completes, does a `RET` to get back to the end of the first, which does a `RET` to jump back to original caller.  However, with a `JMP` at the end of the first, it 'chains' to the second, and the second method's `RET` returns to the caller, saving an extra jump / some stack operations.

---

Depending on what you want to do, you can dynamically generate code in .NET using the Reflection Emit part of the framework ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx ).  You can also use the built-in C# compiler to dynamically compile methods into memory if you want to do it textually.  That *could* be what you're thinking of.

Comment: I almost want to say it's something that takes a list of pointers to whichever functions you specify. The point is, if I have a kernel that has 3 special cases, such as 0<, == 0, and >0, and the specific job I am tasking it to does not make use of the 0< function, I want to cut it out, not have it keep hitting an if/else statement at 2.8 billion cycles / second in a tight while loop. I thought about just putting all the variations in the code, but I'd prefer a non-idiotic approach to this. Plus, if the number of special cases grow, I am going to really start caring.

Comment: In C++, you could have an array of function pointers.  In C#, you would use an event (as Marc's answer) if you want to do it the nice way.  Or you can dynamically generate code using Emit (see updated answer).  Finally, in some performance-crucial areas, e.g. cpu emulators etc, you will see a lot of generated code; generate many methods and source files programatically and use those (you could use that engine .NET uses for razor etc or a cmdline util).  With all this kind of optimisation you'd better be sure you've finished all the algorithms though - don't optimise any earlier than necessary.

Comment: Do you have a link to a C++ sample of an array of function pointers?

Comment: Not really, its incredibly simply - you just create an array of function pointers then call them. http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html tells you about function pointers.  I created an ARM emulator once by translating all 4-byte opcodes into 4-byte function pointers, then just calling each location.  Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be recalling some fragment of the "fluent" coding style found in some APIs?

Each function returns its object instance as the function result, so you can chain together calls like this:

```
obj.Foo()
 .Bar()
 .Moar();
```

There's no particular magical performance boost here, it just saves you from having to type the object instance variable name again and again.

Ok, there may be a very small efficiency gained by using the function result as the instance argument for the next call. If the function result is returned in register EAX and the instance pointer for the next call is passed in register EAX, then this fluent calling pattern saves one or two instructions to load the instance pointer into the EAX register for the next call. But as far as performance tuning goes, this is really really minor.

Comment: No, this is definitely not dot notation. Hmm. Let me try it this way. Foo() adds 2 to the parameter passed in, Bar() divides by 5, and Moar() squares the parameter. By use of this thing, you can have it subscribe to Foo() & Bar(), or Foo() & Bar() & Moar(), or Foo() & Moar(), and so on. and it will take in an integer like 10, so depending on what methods you are subscribed to, the output will differ.

Comment: Ok, was worth a try.  What you're describing sounds more like a function call queue that you'd find inside a script interpreter or expression evaluator.

Comment: ^_^ Sadly, I feel myself going down that path.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `delegate` to solve it